# Make a selection using list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't know much about Excel.

In Sheet A I have a single column list of email addresses.
In Sheet B I have an even bigger list, containing multiple columns - Name, Job, Email etc.  Sheet B contains all the contacts from Sheet A, but also many more.

So what I want to do is cull Sheet B down to only the addresses in Sheet A, but retain all the other data for this selection (such as Name, Job, etc).

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this which come to mind.

If you don't mind making destructive edits to Sheet B, just add a formula to an unused column which uses `COUNTIF()` to check for the presence of that address in Sheet A. Then filter sheet B based on the result of this formula and delete the unwanted rows accordingly.

Alternatively, you could add a `VLOOKUP()` to Sheet A which would return the desired columns from Sheet B, which would be a non-destructive approach.